# Clang 3.8 error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=gold-2.25'

Tags: c++, build, linker, clang, llvm-clang

I am using Clang 3.8 on CentOS 7.4 to compile a C++ app using third party libraries and their (complicated) makefiles. When including their makefile and running my own I am getting the following error during linkage:

```
clang-3.8: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=gold-2.25'
```

I had a look online, some suggestions were to change this to `-fuse-ld=gold`, but still, that didn't work.

Could someone explain what this problem is and how I can fix it?

UPDATE

Also tried `-fuse-ld=lld` but I still get an error:

```
clang-3.8: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clang build does not support linking with gold.

Comment: Hi, I also tried the '-fuse-ld=lld' option and this didn't work either?

Comment: `-fuse-ld=` is not supported alltogether.

Comment: Oh, what would you recommend? I have no knowledge of linking, I just want to create the dynamic library!

Comment: what is the command that you use for linking that gives you the error above?

Comment: LDFLAGS+=-shared -fuse-ld=gold-2.25

Comment: what happens, when you type gold-2.25 in the shell?

Comment: :) Surprise? What if you type `gold`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169662/discussion-between-user997112-and-kaveh-vahedipour).

Comment: Drop the entire `-fuse-ld=...`. Let clang figure it out.

Comment: I now get /..//bin/ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory and then MyObjectFile.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Answer (score 4):

> Also tried -fuse-ld=lld but I still get an error:
> `clang-3.8: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld'`

While this might be *Arch* specific and perhaps not applicable to *CentOS*:

Just minutes ago i was source-building [Godot](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godot) using `scons platform=linuxbsd use_llvm=yes use_lld=yes`, facing the same issue.

Turns out, ***[lld](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/lld/)*** apparently is a separate package. *(trying `ld` seemed to fail in combination)*

So, `yay -S lld` *(or rather `sudo pacman -S lld`)* , resolved the issue straight away.

```
[100%] Linking Program        ==> bin/godot.linuxbsd.tools.64.llvm
```